# Border, Label for a line segment WPF

Tags: wpf, maps, line, border

I am trying to create effects like rail track and streets-with-border-and-label in WPF. How do I add a border to a line segment and a label that is along the line segment? I tried Border class, but it creates a rectangular border.

[image: rail-road]

For the label, I tried [Text on a path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx) but it takes long time for processing as I have > 5000 lines in the canvas.

Any pointers to resources, hints, examples would be very helpful and appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what's your goal, but the vector way is mandatory, IMHO.

Anyway, if the WPF way is too heavy, you may try to create by yourself with the GraphicsPath of GDI+, that allows to manipulate an arbitrary path. The lines are a lot, but maybe once created an optimized version in memory, the calculation could be faster than WPF (which suffers of the animation capability, thus is heavy).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx

Just in case, describe a bit better what's your target project.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for the reply. My goals- 1) make a line look like a road and add a label on it as in the image above . 2) make a line look like a rail track.

Comment: That's right. I still haven't clear what do you have as starting data: a bunch of vectors/paths/lines?

Comment: Yeah. Bunch(a lot) of paths/lines.

Comment: I confirm my solution: draw on a bitmap, using the System.Drawing library. However, you won't have animations...do you need them?

Comment: Just static lines. No animations.

Comment: If you are *NOT* in a hurry, you may send me some sample data (e.g. the lines), and I may setup a minimal sample...in case, drop me an email.

Comment: thanks. that would be helpful. to which id should I email? and how do  you want the data, as in what format?

Comment: My email is "vernarim (at) libero (dot) it". About the data format, I feel comfortable with XML, but any easy-to-interpret format could be okay. Try to send me the data, I'll check for the format.